# Android - Determine Calling Application of an InputMethod (Custom Keyboard)

Tags: android, keyboard, android-service, android-input-method, android-service-binding

I am implementing a custom keyboard following this guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html

Is there a way that from within my KeyboardService which application (=package id) I am 'connected' to (which application receives the input events that I send)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strange, 6 views in a day, thought this topic was more interesting. Well, anyway, I found a solution, here is the code if anyone ever needs it.

From the `InputMethodService` its possible to receive a `InputBinding`:

```
private String getCallerPackageId() {
    InputBinding binding = getCurrentInputBinding();
    return getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getNameForUid(binding.getUid());
}
```

Comment: What is `getCurrentInputBinding()` ?

Comment: What is getCurrentInputBinding()? please give me that method.